# Run a script at startup before login

Tags: login, startup

I want to find out how to run a script made by me at startup before login.

Answer (score 8):

To run a script at startup of Ubuntu, before login, you would edit `/etc/rc.local` and add your desired commands.  Make sure that the script ends with exit 0. <sup>[LSS](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/)</sup>

Comment: This doesn't work for Ngrok on Raspberry Pi.  I still have to login before the command is executed.