# How to Create A Startup Script for Keyboard LED

Tags: 14.04, scripts, keyboard, startup

Freshly installed 14.04, CoolerMaster Storm keyboard. I'm not at all concerned with being able to toggle/turn off the LED, I simply want the LED to turn on *before* login, i.e. while looking at the login screen, the LED should already be on.

I've set up a keyboard shortcut to run `xset led 3`, but this is less than ideal, as I have to be logged in in order to use the shortcut. I'd like this to happen automatically instead.

I'm very new to both Linux and scripting, so please ELI5/walk me through it. I know that you can run scripts at startup as per [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/379290/518089), but I don't understand how to actually write the script or how to "put it in" `/etc/rc.local`. Do I simply fire up gedit and type `xset led 3` directly into `rc.local` below the `#comments`, but above the `exit 0`? Do I make another script somewhere else and link to it in `rc.local`? Am I overthinking it (probably)?

In short, I'd like a more detailed explanation of what Mitch was saying in the link. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should be able to simply add xset to the rc.local and it works, exactly as you said (before the exit 0).  Make sure you edit rc.local with root privileges (open console and type sudo <editor name> /etc/rc.local) and also ensure the file is executable (chmod +x /etc/rc.local)

Comment: @willl459 Tried it, doesn't seem to work, unfortunately. Here's what my `/etc/rc.local` looks like: http://imgur.com/c2ZdCsi. 

I made sure it was executable: http://imgur.com/MavjohI

Comment: That looks correct.  Try the answer by shvahabi [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9853/how-can-i-make-rc-local-run-on-startup).  Steps 1 through 7 seem to be right so try step 8,  type `sudo /etc/init.d/rc.local start` on a terminal and restart.

Comment: @willl459 Please don't recommend starting graphical programs with plain `sudo`. D: Use `sudo -i`.

Comment: Followed that link, shvahabi's steps didn't work for me, either (tried just doing step 8 then rebooting, then going through all of them and rebooting, neither had any effect).

Comment: The (somewhat) good news, though, is that I was able to get it to turn the led automatically at log-in by setting `xset led 3` as a Startup Application. However, this still doesn't have the desired effect of doing the same thing, but without having to log in first (executing *before* login, rather than *at* login).

Comment: in rc.local put the full path to xset. You can figure it out by issuing `which xset`

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal, enter `sudo -s` to get root-access. Now enter `nano /etc/rc.local`, now edit the file so it looks like this:

```
!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

xset led 3
exit 0
```

Now save with **Ctrl + O**, press **enter** and then **Ctrl + X** to exit.

Let's set the proper permissions using:

```
sudo chown root /etc/rc.local
sudo chmod 755 /etc/rc.local
```

Make sure everything works fine using:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rc.local start
```

And now reboot.